PyTorch huge dataset constraints?
I'm training a model in Pytorch to do image-to-image processing. My data is huge, shape is (64152, 3, 5, 2, 64, 144). I'm using memmapping to save on memory as much as humanly possible.
The issues that I'm facing due to the sheer size of this dataset:
1.) shuffling before splitting into train/test sets
2.) normalizing data
Even when memmapping, these operations cause a memory spike that inevitably exceeds the amount of memory I have available on my computer.
I've tried memmapping, normalizing along smaller dimensions at a time. Not sure what to try for shuffling the dataset before splitting into train and test sets.

I am not sure why shuffling data causes you memory spikes: usually, what I would shuffle is the indices of my samples, not my samples themselves. Likewise, regarding memory spikes for normalization: what I would do is (1) calculating my data statistics once (so, say you want to normalize by mapping min-max to 0-1, I would run once over my data and store the min and max value somewhere) and then (2) normalizing each sample when loading it.

Maybe a different question to shed some light: you say you have data of shape (64152, 3, 5, 2, 64, 144). Is that the shape of a single sample or is that the shape of all your samples together? If it is the latter, then which is the sample dimension (i.e. how many samples do you have and what is the shape of each individual sample)?
